# how to divide a value by the day in the month and create a day column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

```
   year  month  name  value1  value2
0  2021    7    cars   5000    4000 
1  2021    7   boats   2000     250
2  2021    9    cars   3000    7000
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
    year  month day  name  value1  value2
0   2021    7    1   cars  161.29  129.03
1   2021    7    2   cars  161.29  129.03
2   2021    7    3   cars  161.29  129.03
3   2021    7    4   cars  161.29  129.03
              ...
31  2021    7    1   boats  64.51   8.064
32  2021    7    2   boats  64.51   8.064
33  2021    7    3   boats  64.51   8.064
              ...
62  2021    9    1    cars   100    233.33
63  2021    9    1    cars   100    233.33
64  2021    9    1    cars   100    233.33
```

The idea is that i want to divide the value columns by the number of days in the month, and create a day column so that in the end i can achieve a date column concatenating year, month and day.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [`monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) from `calendar` to get the number of days in a given month, divide the value by days in the month, then use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to scale up the DataFrame and [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) to add in the Days:

```
from calendar import monthrange

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'year': {0: 2021, 1: 2021, 2: 2021}, 'month': {0: 7, 1: 7, 2: 9},
     'name': {0: 'cars', 1: 'boats', 2: 'cars'},
     'value1': {0: 5000, 1: 2000, 2: 3000},
     'value2': {0: 4000, 1: 250, 2: 7000}})
days_in_month = (
    df[['year', 'month']].apply(lambda x: monthrange(*x)[1], axis=1)
)

# Calculate new values
df.loc[:, 'value1':] = df.loc[:, 'value1':].div(days_in_month, axis=0)
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(days_in_month)]  # Scale Up DataFrame
df.insert(2, 'day', df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1)  # Add Days Column
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)  # Clean up Index
```

`df`:

```
    year  month  day  name      value1      value2
0   2021      7    1  cars  161.290323  129.032258
1   2021      7    2  cars  161.290323  129.032258
2   2021      7    3  cars  161.290323  129.032258
3   2021      7    4  cars  161.290323  129.032258
4   2021      7    5  cars  161.290323  129.032258
..   ...    ...  ...   ...         ...         ...
87  2021      9   26  cars  100.000000  233.333333
88  2021      9   27  cars  100.000000  233.333333
89  2021      9   28  cars  100.000000  233.333333
90  2021      9   29  cars  100.000000  233.333333
91  2021      9   30  cars  100.000000  233.333333
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, but I thought that I dont needed to specify the other columns and rows that I have, but now the dataframe is how it is. If you can help me with this new dataframe i will be very happy

Comment: Code is updated to handle multiple columns.

Comment: Thank you very much, this new code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to create a temp dataframe that will include the days in each month, then merge it, then divide the values

let's assume that you have data single year, so we can create the date range from it straight away, and create the temp dataframe:

```
dt_range = pd.DatFrame(pd.date_range(df.loc[0,'year'] + '-01-01', periods=365))
dt_range.columns = ['dte']
dt_range['year'] = dt_range['dte'].dt.year
dt_range['month'] = dt_range['dte'].dt.month
dt_range['day'] = dt_range['dte'].dt.day
```

now we can create the new dataframe:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df, dt_range,how='left',on=['year','month'])
```

now all we have to do is group by and merge, and we have what you needed

```
new_df = new_df.groupby(['year','month','day']).agg({'value':'mean'})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, but I thought that I dont needed to specify the other columns and rows that I have, but now the dataframe is how it is. If you can help me with this new dataframe i will be very happy

Comment: What dobyou mean? Run the code and the new dataframe will be all set

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resample` to upsample months into days:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2021,7,5000]], columns=['year', 'month', 'value'])

# create datetime column as period
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'].astype(str) + '/' + df['year'].astype(str)).dt.to_period("M")

# calculate values per day by dividing the value by number of days per month
df['ndays'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.days_in_month)
df['value'] = df['value'] / df['ndays']

# set datetime as index and resample:
df = df[['value', 'datetime']].set_index('datetime')
df = df.resample('d').ffill().reset_index()

#split datetime to separate columns
df['day'] = df['datetime'].dt.day
df['month'] = df['datetime'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['datetime'].dt.year
df.drop(columns=['datetime'], inplace=True)
```

|  | value | day | month | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 161.29 | 1 | 7 | 2021 |
| 1 | 161.29 | 2 | 7 | 2021 |
| 2 | 161.29 | 3 | 7 | 2021 |
| 3 | 161.29 | 4 | 7 | 2021 |
| 4 | 161.29 | 5 | 7 | 2021 |

Comment: I will edit the post because my df has more than one month, and using your code I was getting an error because of the multiple months in the df

Comment: What error? It should work on multiple months, try running it on `df = pd.DataFrame([[2021,7,5000],[2021,8,3000],[2021,9,4000]], columns=['year', 'month', 'value'])` for example and you'll see it works.

Comment: I've tested code of @RJ Adriaansenand it works fine with many rows in datarfame. Of course an error may occure if there is duplication in date column, but this is data quality problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume dataframe can have more months, for example extending a little Your initial dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
year    month   value
2021    7   5000
2021    8   5000
2021    9   5000
"""), sep = "\t")
```

Which gives dataframe `df`:

```
   year  month  value
0  2021      7   5000
1  2021      8   5000
2  2021      9   5000
```

Solution is simple one-liner: first datetime index is created from raw `year` and `month`, then resample method is used to convert months to days, finally `value` is overwritten by calculating average per day in every month:

```
df_out = (
     df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df.year, month=df.month, day=1)), freq="MS"))
     .resample('D')
     .ffill()
     .assign(value = lambda df: df.value/df.index.days_in_month)
     )
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
            year  month       value
2021-07-01  2021      7  161.290323
2021-07-02  2021      7  161.290323
2021-07-03  2021      7  161.290323
2021-07-04  2021      7  161.290323
2021-07-05  2021      7  161.290323
         ...    ...         ...
2021-08-28  2021      8  161.290323
2021-08-29  2021      8  161.290323
2021-08-30  2021      8  161.290323
2021-08-31  2021      8  161.290323
2021-09-01  2021      9  166.666667
```

Please note September has only 30 days, so `value` is different than in previous months.

Comment: You were right, my df has more months, it has a name column too, but when I try your code I get this error:          ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency MS

Comment: I was able to generate the same error as You, when I run the second part of the code twice.  I've modified the code to create `df_out` and to not modify initial dataframe `df`. Please check if it helps. Of course You have to create/read `df` once again.